# How to concatenate two classes (plain and binded) in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I need element with 2 classes. The first I receive from my scope and second class is always constant. How can i concatenate them in template?

```
  <template>
    <div class="b-item-additional-menu">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menu}}" as="item">
          <span class$="{{item.className}}"></span>
      </template>
      <mail-item-menu-dropdown></mail-item-menu-dropdown>
    </div>
</template>
```

I need result `<span class$="binded_class plain_class"></span>`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute use [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) as string concatenations are not supported in Polymer 1.0.

```
<span class$="{{computeClass(item.className)}}"></span>
```

And you define the `computeClass` function in the prototype of your element.

```
Polymer({
   is: "my-element",
   computedClass: function(class) {
       return plain_class +" " +class;
   }
```